# How to use php and jquery to produce a multilevel json structure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to product an output like the below, but I don't know how to do it, any help?

```
{  
   "messages":[  
      {  
         "from":"InfoSMS",
         "to":[  
            "41793026727",
            "41793026731"
         ],
         "text":"May the Force be with you!"
      },
      {  
         "from":"41793026700",
         "to":"41793026785",
         "text":"A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away... It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire."
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you want to create this structure in PHP or in jQuery? How do you store your original data?

Comment: yes i want php and jquery code that can produce the above output.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to how their syntax's differ. I first provide a way to define it in PHP and then I show you a way to define it in JavaScript:

```
<?php

$json = Array( 
   "messages" => Array(   
      Array( 
         "from" => "InfoSMS",
         "to" => Array(   
            "41793026727",
            "41793026731"
         ),
         "text" => "May the Force be with you!"
      ),
      Array(   
         "from" => "41793026700",
         "to" => "41793026785",
         "text" => "A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away... It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire."
      )
   )
);

print_r($json);

?>

<script>

json = {  
   "messages":[  
      {  
         "from":"InfoSMS",
         "to":[  
            "41793026727",
            "41793026731"
         ],
         "text":"May the Force be with you!"
      },
      {  
         "from":"41793026700",
         "to":"41793026785",
         "text":"A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away... It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire."
      }
   ]
};

console.log(json);

</script>
```

PHP's eval.in:

https://eval.in/753090

Javascript:

https://eval.in/753091

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_encode()` on your PHP array to convert it to JSON. You'll need to generate something like this from a dataset.

```
$data = [
    'messages'=> [
        [
            'from' => 'InfoSMS',
            'to' => [
                '41793026727',
                '41793026731',
            ],
            'text' => 'May the Force be with you!',
        ],
        [
            'from' => '41793026700',
            'to' => [
                '41793026785',
            ],
            'text' => 'A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away... It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire.',
        ],
    ],
];

echo json_encode($data);
```